# Promise reject - timeout logging placement

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I've a promise race implementation for timeout. I want to log a timeout error in case of timeout.

The problem is it logs even when the fetch was successful, as it runs in parallel and still executes after the timeout.

Where to place `errorLogger.info(message)` so that it doesn't get executed in `non-timeout` case? I think I'm putting it wrongly so it outputs before it actually rejects.

```
return Promise.race([
   fetch(url, options)
  .then(function (response) {
    if (response.status >= 400) {
      const message = `fetch-utility.js: bad server response while fetching url=${url} with options=${options}.`;


      errorLogger.error(`${message} Response: status=${response.status} statusText:${response.statusText}.`);

      throw new BadServerResponseException(message, response.status);
    }
    return response;
  }),
  new Promise((_, reject) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      const message = `fetch-utility.js: timeout happened while fetching details url=${url} with options=${options}. 
  The timeout set is ${timeout}.`;

      // TODO: this gets logged even the parallel wins - need to see better way to log this
      // errorLogger.error(message);

      reject(new TimeoutException(message));
    }, timeout),
  ),
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not wise to have the timeout logic mixed in with your actual business logic. You should abstract out the timeout logic, which will allow you to do this:

```
function timeoutPromise(timeout) {
    return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, timeout));
}

function withTimeout(timeout, promise, timeoutMessage) {
    let done = false;

    return Promise.race([
        Promise.resolve(promise)
            .finally(() => { done = true }),
        timeoutPromise(timeout)
            .then(() => {
                if (!done) {
                    const message = timeoutMessage || `Timeout after ${timeout} ms`;

                    errorLogger.error(message);

                    throw new TimeoutException(message);
                }
            })
   ]);
}

const timeout = 12345;

function performFetch(url, options) {
    return fetch(url, options)
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.status >= 400) {
                const message = `fetch-utility.js: bad server response while fetching url=${url} with options=${options}.`;

                errorLogger.error(`${message} Response: status=${response.status} statusText:${response.statusText}.`);

                throw new BadServerResponseException(message, response.status);
            }

            return response;
        });
}

withTimeout(
    timeout, 
    performFetch(url, options),
   `fetch-utility.js: timeout happened while fetching details url=${url} with options=${options}. The timeout set is ${timeout}.`
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not log the error inside those two constructs, as then it will indeed always be called.

Instead you could chain a `then` and `catch` on the promise returned by `Promise.race`. So you would keep the arguments to `race` very slim, and move the logic to the outer part.

Something like:

```
return Promise.race([
    fetch(url, options),
    new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject("timeout"), timeout))
]).catch(function(error) {
    if (error === "timeout") {
        const message = "timeout happened";
        errorLogger.error(message);
        throw new TimeoutException(message);
    } else {
        const message = "fetch failed";
        errorLogger.error(message);
        throw new FetchException(message);
    }
}).then(function (response) {
    if (response.status >= 400) {
        const message = "bad response";
        errorLogger.error(message);
        throw new BadServerResponseException(message, response.status);
    }
    return response; // Success within timeout!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question 100% but if you want to "cancel" a promise if it takes too long to return something may be you can do something like this

```
function myRequest() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var mytimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('We are sorry but your request took too long');
            reject({
                err: "timed out"
            });
        }, 10)

        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(res => {
            resolve(res);
            clearTimeout(mytimeout)
        });
    });    
}

var promise = myRequest()
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Try changing the timeout value of `setTimeout`, for small enough values it will throw an exception and with relatively large timeout it will resolve the promise with data